# Why would an iframe's history get added to the history

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile I am using an iframe. When you press the back button (in the app or the browsers back button) the iframe content goes away. Then when you press the back button again the app transitions to the previous page.

The iFrame is getting added to history. I thought this was never supposed to happen.

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/6achL3ez/) has been created that illustrates the puzzle in as simple a form as possible.

In it you will find a fragment of HTML that creates two jQuery Mobile pages.  On the first page there is a link to go to the second page.  On the second page,there are two back buttons (one on the header and one as a button on the page) and also a button to reload the `<iframe>`.  To recreate the problem:

- From page 1 follow the link to page 2
- On page 2, click the button to load the `<iframe>`
- Click either of the back buttons

You will notice that you do **not** go back to page 1.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <p>This is page 1</p> <a href="#page2">Go to page 2</a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
         <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <p>This is page 2</p>
    <p>What follows is the iFrame</p>
    <iframe id="i1" width="500" src="http://www.ibm.com"></iframe>
    <p>This button issues a programmatic back</p>
    <button id="backButton">Go Back</button>
    <p>This button loads new content into the iframe</p>
    <button id="reloadButton">Reload iFrame</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("#backButton").click(function () {
        jQuery.mobile.back();
    });
    $("#reloadButton").click(function() {
        $("#i1").attr("src", "http://www.microsoft.com?x=" + Math.random());
    });
});
```

(This is the code you will find in the jsFiddle).

Comment: It looks like this puzzle has been around for a while ... see also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-265  here is another useful link http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/iframe-and-browser-history

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is because JQM programatically manipulates the history with [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). You can read more about how they track history in an ajax environment in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

Show me some code or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and I may be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

One answer that seems to work (so far) is **not** to attempt to reload the `<iframe>` via changing its `src` attribute but instead, inserting a brand new `<iframe>` element to replace the one that was previously there.  The logic to achieve this might look as follows:

```
$("#frameLocation").html('<iframe id="i1" width="500" src=' + newURL + '"></iframe>');
```

A corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/322Lgo6h/) showing it working is available.

This has been tested on Chrome 38.0 and Internet Explorer 11.0.